Finding User Home Directories and Modifying Permissions in Ubuntu on AWS
I have an AWS Ubuntu server, and I need to locate a specific user account. I'm having trouble finding the folder associated with this user. Additionally, I'm trying to create a folder, but I'm encountering issues because the directory is set to read-only access.
There are many users on the system, and I need a command that can help me locate the user's home directory or relevant folders quickly. I've tried the following command to search for a folder named "ftp_folder," but it's not returning any results:
ssh -i /path/to/your-key.pem ec2-user@your-ec2-instance-public-ip
sudo find / -type d -name "ftp_folder"
Can you help me with a more effective way to find the user's folder or check their permissions?

You can check the user's home directory using the getent passwd username command. To find a specific folder, like "ftp_folder," you can use the find command. If the directory is read-only, you may need to check the permissions and modify them if necessary.

I attempted to use the command sudo find / -type d -name 'ftp_folder', but it did not work due to security restrictions. I am unable to provide the exact details.

Perfect I have found the answer.  thank you

I have changed to 755 permission.
